# How to assign roles with a command - discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I wanted to give my bot the functionality to assign roles with a command

For example, `+mod @user` would give `@user` the role of Mod.

Code in my `main.js`:

```
if(command == 'mod'){
    client.commands.get('mod').execute(message, args);
}
```

Code in my `mod.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'mod',
    description: "This command gives member the Mod role",
    execute(message, args){
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        member.roles.add('role ID xxxx');
    }
}
```

I get an error saying the member is empty. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it said `member` is empty. `users` don't have roles though, `members` have. So you will need to get the first [mentioned `member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members) instead.

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'mod',
  description: 'This command gives member the Mod role',
  async execute(message, args) {
    const member = message.mentions.members.first();
    if (!member) {
      return message.reply('you need to mention someone');
    }
    try {
      await member.roles.add('ROLE_ID');
      message.reply(`${member} is now a mod `);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      message.reply('Oops, there was an error');
    }
  },
};
```